# Serilog seems to be ignoring log level when deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

We have serilog enabled for our `.net6` web apps, and deployed within Azure App Services, to log to Elastic

Locally, the log levels appear to be adhered to, but when we deploy to Azure, it  just seems to be ignored and log `Information` and `Debug` messages, and not use the min log level that was actually set.

The `Program.cs` is as so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async static Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(message => Console.WriteLine(message));

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting");
                await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, $"host terminated unexpectedly {ex}");
                return 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                 {
                     webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                 })
                 .UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

And the Serilog section with AppSettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch"],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "nodeUris": "https://<<<ELASTICHOST>>>",
          "indexFormat": "logs-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
          "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=ApiKey <<<KEY>>>>;",
          "emitEventFailure": "WriteToSelfLog",
          "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
          "registerTemplateFailure": "IndexAnyway",
          "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": "ESv7",
          "batchPostingLimit": 50,
          "batchAction": "Create",
          "period": 2,
          "inlineFields": true,
          "deadLetterIndexName": "deadletter-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext"],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyAzureAppServiceApp",
      "Environment": "Live"
    }
  }
```

The settings in the specific app service are as so:

```
Serilog__MinimumLevel__Default = Warning
Serilog__MinimumLevel__Override__Microsoft = Warning
Serilog__MinimumLevel__Override__System = Warning
```

[image]

Comment: Add  `.MinimumLevel.Information()` after `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()` and check once.

Comment: But I don't want information logs - as per my settings - I want warning logs, but it's logging information. We have different log levels on Prod and Dev, so I need them configurable

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by

> it just seems to be ignored

you mean that you cannot see it in Application Insigths logs correct?

In order to see logs in Application Insigths logs you have to use [Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights).

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights("InstrumentationKeyHere", TelemetryConverter.Traces, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
                .Build();
```

I modified your code and added one line. The added line tells Serilog to treat your log as Application Insigtht log traces.

Comment: Nope - never said anything about AI - I should perhaps be more clear (and will edit as so). It logs to elastic - but it ignores the log levels set and just seems to log everything, inc debug - when the min level was set

Comment: Oh I see. What type of app service plan are you using? Linux or Windows?
There is a difference for config convention:  https://ppolyzos.com/2021/07/29/how-to-set-nested-app-settings-in-windows-and-linux-azure-app-service/

otherwise your config seems OK from what I can see in your post

Comment: Oh lord! We're using windows ones - but the linux convention is working fine for other things - I'll try it..

Comment: That's had no effect